# Comparator and configurations with capacitors

Tags: comparator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjiDKF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Is it possible to configure comparators as integrator just as we do with op-amps?
- Why in some designs there is a big capacitor (<1µF) at the output of comparator?
- How does adding a capacitor in negative feedback or at the output affect the slew rate of comparator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, no it is not possible. There is no access to the internal nodes required to compensate the amplifier (prevent it from oscillating).

The [LM393](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group1/b4/cc/cf/13/18/28/44/f5/CD00000465/files/CD00000465.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000465.pdf) and related chips have an exceptionally simple design (and an input very similar to that of an op-amp- albeit operated at a much higher current) so it is possible with a pullup resistor, optional transistor, and a BFC on the output.

[image]

Note the "\$\mu\$" symbol is missing on the below capacitor values.

[image]

Of course it won't be a very **good** op-amp but it might be useful in some particular circumstances where you need a real comparator elsewhere and you have a dual or quad comparator chip. The slew rate of the resulting op-amp will be asymmetrical and very slow. With the given value of 500nF and 15kΩ the time constant is 7.5ms. It might be usable for an integrator under some circumstances, but maybe you also need a cap on the output.

Comment: I was reading some application notes ([page 11](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa35b/snoaa35b.pdf)) and they mentioned that the output capacitor should not be connected directly to the output but with a resistor, why your examples are missing that resistor?

Comment: The note refers to comparator applications (output switching). The 393 also has pretty wimpy sink capacity so "amperes" are never going to flow, it's a bit of a hyperbolic statement. Typically it maxes out at about 20mA. Not especially nice, but it's a nasty circuit and I don't really recommend it.  With the kind of series resistor they are suggesting,  it will not perform the required function (compensation) in the op-amp application.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're reading the question the way I see it: it doesn't seem to be about converting a comparator into an op-amp, but about adding an integrating function to a comparator. I've built those and they oscillate as you'd predict, but they don't need any compensation besides that. The whole point I believe is to make them an oscillator by adding the (poor-man's) integrating action. Otherwise, what would be the point of using a comparator for this?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica If you have an LM339 and need one op-amp you could avoid spending the few pennies to buy an LM358. Hence the comparator datasheet examples I snipped. If you want to make an oscillator with a comparator you'd use an RC circuit on the inverting input and positive fb on the non-inverting and the results would be very predictable and consistent. OP's schematic shows a comparator used as an op-amp integrator, and oscillation would likely be undesirable (at least I can't think of any reason  to want it).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think you're right.